# How to define array of strings in interface?

Tags: typescript

I tried this:

```
export interface ITarifFeatures {
  key: string;
}


export interface ITarif {
   features: ITarifFeatures[];
}
```

Then I have create object based on interface:

```
let obj<ITarif> {
      name: "Базовый",
      description: "Подходит для...",
      currency: "A",
      price: 1.99,
      period: "Месяц",
      features: ["СМС уведомления"]
    };
```

But this property is wrong:

```
features: ["СМС уведомления"]
```

Also I tried:

```
export type ITarifFeatures = {
  key: string[];
}

export interface ITarif {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  currency: string;
  price: number;
  period: string;
  features: ITarifFeatures
}
```

Comment: `features: string[]`

Comment: That is right, but I want to use custom type for further extending properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `interface` type `ITarifFeatures` expects a property called `key` that you are not supplying, you are passing an instance of `string` type `["СМС уведомления"]` in the array instead, so modify the code to this:

```
export interface ITarifFeatures {
  key: string;
}
export interface ITarif {
    features: ITarifFeatures[];
    [x: string]: any 
}

let itarif: ITarifFeatures = {key: "СМС уведомления"};
let obj: ITarif = {
      name: "Базовый",
      description: "Подходит для...",
      currency: "A",
      price: 1.99,
      period: "Месяц",
      features: [itarif]
};
```

Also, the `ITarif` type will only accept `features` property, but you are trying to supply more key-values to it. To circumvent it add an *indexer* `[x: string]: any` 
 in the original interface.

Answer (score 1):

String type != ITarifFeatures

What is need is an object like this:

```
{
    key:'blabla'
}
```